# How can a ensure a database user has privileges to make backups while I'm upgrading to CockroachDB 22.2?

Tags: authorization, backup, cockroachdb

In CockroachDB 22.2, the SELECT grant no longer applies on the database level, and you don't need it in order to take a backup. But in earlier versions if the user does not have SELECT on the database it fails to take a backup. Is there another way to allow backups that would work with both 21.1.x and 22.2.x so that I'm never in a state where my backup user can't take backups during the upgrade process?

Answer (score 1):

As part of your upgrade process, when you are on 21.2.x you can grant the CONNECT privilege on the database that needs to be backed up, and drop the SELECT privilege. You can then continue your upgrade to 22.1 -> 22.2. In 21.2, 22.1 and 22.2 a backup of a database will accept the CONNECT privilege as sufficient.

Once you've finalized your upgrade to 22.2 you can just use the [BACKUP privilege](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/backup.html#required-privileges).